# Sqlite doesn't find row _only_ when binding takes places in another function

Tags: c++, sqlite

So I wrote myself a little wrapper function to make a prepared statement for me:

```
sqlite3_stmt* Gladiateur::run_query_unfinalized(string query, vector<string> inputs){

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    // Prepare SQL
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), -1, &statement, NULL);

    // Bind parameter
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, inputs[0].c_str(), -1, NULL);

    return statement;

}
```

Normally it would go through the inputs vector and bind all of the strings, but I simplified the code to find out where the error lies.

I have another function set_list (also simplified):

```
int Gladiateur::set_list (string list_name) {

    vector<string> bind = {list_name};
    sqlite3_stmt *statement = this->run_query_unfinalized("SELECT id FROM lists WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1", bind);

    printf("code %d\n", sqlite3_step(statement));

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    return 1;

}
```

I call set_list, and I get "code 101", which simply implies that there were no SQL-errors but no row was retrieved. I know that a matching row exists, though.

And here comes the weird part: I move the line

`sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, inputs[0].c_str(), -1, NULL);`

into the set_list function, just above the printf, and write `bind[0]` instead of `inputs[0]`. And it works! I get "code 100", the row is found, it also gave me the correct id when I checked.

But I want to do all the binding in `run_query_unfinalized`... and I am really confused why it doesn't work. Maybe I can't pass the `statement` variable like that?

Comment: Not checking the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` will blow up sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter of the [sqlite3_bind_text](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) function cannot be NULL:

> The fifth argument to the BLOB and string binding interfaces is a destructor used to dispose of the BLOB or string after SQLite has finished with it. The destructor is called to dispose of the BLOB or string even if the call to bind API fails. If the fifth argument is the special value [SQLITE_STATIC](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_static.html), then SQLite assumes that the information is in static, unmanaged space and does not need to be freed. If the fifth argument has the value [SQLITE_TRANSIENT](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_static.html), then SQLite makes its own private copy of the data immediately, before the sqlite3_bind_*() routine returns.

In this case, you need `SQLITE_TRANSIENT`.

Answer (score 1):

> `Gladiateur::run_query_unfinalized(string query, vector<string> inputs)`

The `vector<string> inputs` is a copy, and it ceases to exist when the function returns.

Perhaps you should change it to:

```
Gladiateur::run_query_unfinalized(const string& query, const vector<string>& inputs)
```

With a reference, the `c_str` should survive to do what you want to get done.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I guess I misunderstood the way bind works.

Comment: @Vincent - no problem. I figured you were a Java guy when I saw it. Valgrind probably would have complained, but it takes a while to learn how to use it correctly.

Comment: Yes, it does! But it's fun to learn something new. One thing though: If I try to pass the array literally (`this->run_query_unfinalized("...", {list_name})`), it gives me the same problem. What can I do about that?

Comment: Get rid of the `this->`.  It clutters the code.  Second: Cannot duplicate: http://ideone.com/9t4OpG